# CORs with domain name does not work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an Web API application. My Angular web UI calls the web API.
I have modified the application to make the http calls like below

```
var urlString = SomeSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + 'api/Test';
var getData = function (urlString) {----}
```

I also have enabled the Cors in Web Api config as below.

```
 //Enable Cors
        //Right now adding URLs for Dev and QA
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://DevAPIURL.com, http://QAAPIURL.com", "*", "*");
//            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        cors.SupportsCredentials = true;

        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

With this setting, if I am ***debugging*** the application I am getting the  "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied." error. I dont see the access-control-allow-origin header in fiddler as well

However if I use * instead of the domain names, I am able to work.

What else is going wrong in this.

Comment: While authenticating I am making the call to /Token path. This does not work even if I have enabled CORs for all domains by giving * as the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. Some one in another thread also had suggested but I kind of ignored that. Here is the solution

I installed the Microsoft.Owin.Cors and then in the startup.Auth.cs class I added the below line as the 2st line in ConfigureAuth method.`install-package Microsoft.Owin.Cors`

Thats it.

I removed the configuration from WebWPIConfig.cs class.

Testted both authentication and API Controller method all worked.